# Why is Vue-echarts not displaying anything in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, echarts

My vue-echarts is not included in the dom. I am using the code from this link.

[GitHub (npmjs.com)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-echarts)

I am using the vue2  version with the latest version of nuxt.

```html
<template>
  <v-chart class="chart" :option="option" />
</template>

<script>
import { use } from "echarts/core"
import { CanvasRenderer } from "echarts/renderers"
import { PieChart } from "echarts/charts"
import {
  TitleComponent,
  TooltipComponent,
  LegendComponent
} from "echarts/components"
import VChart, { THEME_KEY } from "vue-echarts"

use([
  CanvasRenderer,
  PieChart,
  TitleComponent,
  TooltipComponent,
  LegendComponent
])

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    VChart
  },
  provide: {
    [THEME_KEY]: "dark"
  },
  data() {
    return {
      option: {
        title: {
          text: "Traffic Sources",
          left: "center"
        },
        tooltip: {
          trigger: "item",
          formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)"
        },
        legend: {
          orient: "vertical",
          left: "left",
          data: [
            "Direct",
            "Email",
            "Ad Networks",
            "Video Ads",
            "Search Engines"
          ]
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: "Traffic Sources",
            type: "pie",
            radius: "55%",
            center: ["50%", "60%"],
            data: [
              { value: 335, name: "Direct" },
              { value: 310, name: "Email" },
              { value: 234, name: "Ad Networks" },
              { value: 135, name: "Video Ads" },
              { value: 1548, name: "Search Engines" }
            ],
            emphasis: {
              itemStyle: {
                shadowBlur: 10,
                shadowOffsetX: 0,
                shadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.chart {
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

I had an error earlier that said: **SyntaxError Unexpected token 'export'**  but resolved it with the solution provided on the link :

https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts/issues/536

What could be causing the chart to be not included in the DOM.

Comment: Is the rest of your Vue app rendered in the DOM? Do you have a main.js file that calls `createApp(App).mount('#app')` and a `<div id="app"></div>` in your index.html? Your code is fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-dan-hf659?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, All I needed was to include the following [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/composition-api):

```
buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/composition-api/module"]
```

in my  `nuxt.config.js`  file.

My `package.json` file needed both of the following packages installed as well:

```
  "devDependencies": {
        "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "^0.29.2",
        "@vue/composition-api": "^1.2.2"
   }
```

A working version can be found at [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxtjs-vue-echarts-forked-ux71k?file=/package.json:328-351).